# CSS to couple link text and CSS triangle

Tags: css

I'm using a CSS triangle to create a navigation arrow. Here's the stripped-down example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Triangle</title>
<style>
.nav {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav a:link, .nav a:visited, .nav a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
}
.arrow-right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 12px solid #000000;
}
.arrow-right:hover {
    border-left-color: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='nav'><a href='http://example.com'>Next <div class='arrow-right'></div></a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you mouse-hover on the arrow, both the text and the arrow turn red, as expected. But if you mouse-hover only on the text, only the text turns red. Is there a reasonably simple way to "couple" these in the CSS, so that hovering on *either* produces the color change? I don't want the entire box to be an anchor - just the text and the arrow.

(I've also used some UTF-8 characters to make the arrows, but that triggers some interesting font-rendering problems on a Mac. Using » and « is appealing, but the lack of good "up" and "down" entities makes that one kind of a non-starter. Using images is out, because I need complete color flexibility.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
.arrow-right:hover {
    border-left-color: #ff0000;
}
```

to:

```
.nav a:hover .arrow-right {
    border-left-color: #ff0000;
}
```

---

[**DEMO 01**](http://jsfiddle.net/9JPXP/) - Coupling anchor and element border

---

or if you want to combine them by changing :

```
.nav a:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

to:

```
.nav a:hover, .nav a:hover .arrow-right {
    color: #ff0000;
    border-left-color: #ff0000;
}
```

and remove this completely:

```
/* remove this */
.arrow-right:hover {
    border-left-color: #ff0000;
}
```

---

[**DEMO 02**](http://jsfiddle.net/X7562/) - Couple anchor and element border

---

Comment: Looks like just what I'm after. CSS selectors are still sometimes a bit murky for me. Thanks!

Comment: @fnostro: I added a solution using the separated CSS as well now in case the combined selectors become an issue due to a border on the anchor.

Comment: @MisterNeutron: That murkiness hopefully only get's less as we move ahead. CSS3 has given us a lot to play with and CSS4 add even more. The current CSS4 selectors module for example proposes a parent selector (yay) which at this time is proposed to look similar to this: `!div>h3{...}` this would look for any `div` which has a `h3` as a child, i.e: `<div><h3></h3></div>` **but** apply the style to the parent, the `div`, instead of the `h3` element. That is only early stages of the proposal though so nothing carved in stone. Either way it looks exciting what is to come :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the hover selector on the nav as follows:

```
nav:hover a, nav:hover .arrow-right{color: red;}
```

Also, for the sake of best practice add the focus selectors too:

```
nav:hover a, nav:focus a, nav:hover .arrow-right, nav:focus .arrow-right{color: red;}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference. Remember, "arrow-right" isn't a character, so "color" doesn't mean anything in that context.

Comment: You could try using an angle bracket as an arrow ">" or "->" or ">>"

Comment: use border-left-color